# Add border lines to bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]enter image description hereI have a grid created using class col-md-3 which have 3 columns:

```
<div ng-repeat='(key, value) in permissionsViewContent' class="row">
    <div class="tree_content_permissions_title">
        <span> {{key}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="val in value"
        class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
        <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> 
            {{val}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

this grid created from a list of values. I want my grid to have border line after each row in my grid. How can I do it using css?

Thanks,

Comment: `.row{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}` did you try this?

Comment: the answer to this question is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123307/angular-js-conditional-markup-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can use `<hr/>` tags where you want

You can use like this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/CfYe5Q4MR2)

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="tree_content_permissions_title">
                <span>asd</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="sadfdsf" />
                        sdfsdf
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        sdfsdf
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        sdfsdf
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="sadfdsf" />
                        sdfsdf
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        sdfsdf
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        sdfsdf
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a image? to show excatly what you are looking for

Comment: Hi... I can't do it, since I have dynamic data in a list I can't wrap each 3 columns with "row" class.

Comment: How you are binding the dynamic datas ? can you show your code or fiddle

Answer (score 0):

What about adding this then [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zg1rrnst/3/embedded/result/)

```
<div ng-repeat='(key, value) in permissionsViewContent'>
    <div  class="row">
        <div class="tree_content_permissions_title">
            <span> {{key}}</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="val in value"
            class="col-md-3 tree_content_permissions">
            <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox"> 
                {{val}}
            </label>


        </div>
    </div>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried, but this is not what I want, I want to add the border not after the "row" class, but after each 3 columns are created Inside the row

Comment: This is more close to what I am trying to do, but the problem is that it creates small lines under each cell and not one long under all the row

Comment: use <hr> before closing of <div class="row"> div then it will be after each row

Comment: This is not working. as I said, I need the lines after each 3 columns and not after each row. the rows are all content under my title, like in the image I attached. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59986/discussion-between-orikoko-and-dev).