# ng-repeat should work only where parent div has id 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have requirement where i need to make ng-repeat work only at one place. i will define id where it should work something like this.I want to do this from controller

`$(#1).(ng-repeat work)` something like this

eg:

```
 <table id="1">
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
<td></td> 
</table>

<table id="2">
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
<td></td> 
</table>
```

Fiddle link:-http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/580/

How to acheive this

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean work only at one place?

Comment: What would you want to happen elsewhere?

Comment: how these table id="x" are generated ? by script ? is the id somewhere in the model ? Because other will correct me if I'm wrong but I don't see something in angular to use the id of an element to add or not an ng-repeat

Comment: @ James Waddington at other places nothing will happen

Comment: @Wawy only one place means where id ==1 there only it should work at other places it will remainsame

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

(1) Use `ng-show` in your code.

```
<table id="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="/* code to check parent id */">
  <td></td> </tr>
</table>

<table id="2">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="/* code to check parent id */">
  <td></td> </tr>
</table>
```

This may be a littlte inperformant.

(2) Only use ng-repeat when you need it. If this is generated by php code, check there if `$i == 1` and do not echo ng-repeat if not.

(3) Use conditional `ng-repeat`'s as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123307/angular-js-conditional-markup-in-ng-repeat).

EDIT: Sorry for the strange list, the code doesn't show if it's done the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand question, you have to define new model for items which should be displayed in #1, and other one to be displayed #2. Fill first model with data to be displayed in #1 (using Js), and the same for second model. Then bind another models like this:

```
<table id="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items1">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td> 
</table>

<table id="2">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items2">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td> 
</table>
```

Comment: i cant make two different model

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is to show/hide the ng-repeat contents as per the id that is to be passed.

I have an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/582/) to handle precisely that.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table id="1" border=1>
        <tr ng-repeat="line in lines" ng-show="line.id == 1">
            <td>{{line.text}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="2" border=1 style="margin-top:10px">
        <tr ng-repeat="line in lines" ng-show="line.id == 2">
            <td>{{line.text}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lines = [{
        id: 1,
        text: 'res1'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        text: 'res2'
    }];
}
```

UPDATE (json without the id attribute):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/585/)

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table id="1" border=1>
        <tr ng-repeat="line in lines" ng-show="id == 1">
            <td>{{line.text}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="2" border=1 style="margin-top:10px">
        <tr ng-repeat="line in lines" ng-show="id == 2">
            <td>{{line.text}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.id = 1;
    $scope.lines = [{
        text: 'res1'
    }, {
        text: 'res2'
    }];
}
```

Comment: i dont want to pass id from json

Comment: That is an example...however you can have the id be passed elsewhere and can use ng-show in order to set its display on/off.

Comment: can we controll the same from controller

Comment: the controller can set the id value and thus be controlled from their on. ng-show will take the latest of the id value and change by itself.